# View Handlers in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

// My form View

```
App.Form = Em.View.extend({
    templateName:'app/templates/Login/login'    
});
```

// Index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars"> 
    Hello <b>{{App.Value}}</b>  
       <div id="frm">
            {{#view App.Form}}

        {{/view}}
       </div>                   
</script>
```

//login.handlebars

```
<b>Login Page: </b>
```

Couple of questions.

1. When i load my index.html, it does not call the login handlebars. I am not able to see the bold text out there.
2. After i had made an ajax call checking my credentials, how to redirect my user to another view or page.

Comment: can u post a fiddle? question is quite unclear on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Form = Em.View.extend({
    templateName:'loginTemplate'    
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loginTemplate"> 
  <b>Login Page: </b>
</script>
```

This should do I guess...In order to redirect to pages u can try Ember.Router

Comment: What does the template do here. Can you show me an example where i read something from loginTemplate.handlebars to display in my handlers in index.html